# Ubuntu server 11.10 with LAMP. Installing gd breaks php (or apache?)

Tags: php, apache, gd

I just installed a clean ubuntu server 11.10 with lamp (from the ubuntu installer). 
The server was working nicely and running php in apache.

However, upon installing gd:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

The server has been broken, that is, it will just output php-files as text without interpretation.
I checked the httpd.conf and it is cleared

Does anyone know how to remedy the situation?

EDIT

After reinstalling the server from scratch I tried stopping the server **before** installing gd, and it worked for me.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
sudo apt-get install php5-gd 
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

Comment: Then restart the Apache server to load php modules - sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart